# Python excel spread sheet comparison

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas

I am currently attempting to write a script to compare the contents of two excel files.

List 1 will have the following format;

```
Broadcom Drivers and Management Applications  [version 17.0.8.2]
QLogic Drivers and Management Applications  [version 18.00.8.3]
NVIDIA 3D Vision Driver 306.97  [version 306.97]
Citrix online plug-in (Web)  [version 12.1.0.30]
Citrix online plug-in (HDX)  [version 12.1.0.30]
Google Update Helper  [version 1.3.32.7]
QfinitiPatches_20131211_Win7 [version 1.0.0.0]
Citrix online plug-in (Web)  [version 12.1.0.30]
Citrix online plug-in (HDX)  [version 12.1.0.30]
Citrix Receiver (HDX Flash Redirection)  [version 14.3.1.1]
Citrix Authentication Manager  [version 7.0.0.8243]
Microsoft Office Access MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]
Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]
Microsoft Office PowerPoint MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]
Microsoft Office Publisher MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]
```

List 2 will have the following format;

```
Mcrosoft Word (All versions)
Microsoft Excel (All versions)
Microsoft Access (All versions)
Microsoft Project (All versions)
Microsoft PowerPoint (All versions)
Microsoft Infopath (All versions)
Microsoft Visio (All versions)
Microsoft SQL Server (All versions)
Microsoft SQL Client (All versions)
Microsoft explorer (version 6+)
Firefox (version 2+)
Oracle Database (All versions)
```

What i need the script to do, is to use list 2 as a reference and look for any matching contents in list 1. Because the two lists do not match exactly i need to make sure that it will pick up partial matches.

For example, in list 1 there is *Microsoft Office Access MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]*, whereas list two has *Microsoft Access (All versions)* and i would need the script to pick this up as a match and omit this from the output file.

So far i have the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_excel('/xls comparison project/xl files/Approved Software list.xls', 'Approved Software', parse_cols = 'd', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_excel('/xls comparison project/xl files/Software list.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols = 'a')
import csv
AS = df1["Software Title"].tolist()
S = df2["Software"].tolist()
```

I tried the below but this looked for exact matches

```
result = [ x for x in AS if x in S]
```

I have loaded the contents of both spreadsheets into variables called AS and S in a list format. then;

```
results = result
resultfile = open("output1.xls",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(resultfile, delimiter=',')
for val in result:
    wr.writerow([val])
resultfile.close()
```

This gives me the output file i need

The only issue i have is actually comparing the data, i have run out of ideas.

I have googled extensively and although i can find similar problems i have been unable to create a solution from their content. I am fairly new to python, so i appreciate any help you can give me.

Many thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(['Broadcom Drivers and Management Applications  [version 17.0.8.2]','QLogic Drivers and Management Applications  [version 18.00.8.3]','NVIDIA 3D Vision Driver 306.97  [version 306.97]','Citrix online plug-in (Web)  [version 12.1.0.30]','Citrix online plug-in (HDX)  [version 12.1.0.30]','Google Update Helper  [version 1.3.32.7]','QfinitiPatches_20131211_Win7 [version 1.0.0.0]','Citrix online plug-in (Web)  [version 12.1.0.30]','Citrix online plug-in (HDX)  [version 12.1.0.30]','Citrix Receiver (HDX Flash Redirection)  [version 14.3.1.1]','Citrix Authentication Manager  [version 7.0.0.8243]','Microsoft Office Access MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]','Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]','Microsoft Office PowerPoint MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]','Microsoft Office Publisher MUI (English) 2010  [version 14.0.6029.1000]'], columns=['Software Title'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Mcrosoft Word (All versions)','Microsoft Excel (All versions)','Microsoft Access (All versions)','Microsoft Project (All versions)','Microsoft PowerPoint (All versions)','Microsoft Infopath (All versions)','Microsoft Visio (All versions)','Microsoft SQL Server (All versions)','Microsoft SQL Client (All versions)','Microsoft explorer (version 6+)','Firefox (version 2+)','Oracle Database (All versions)'], columns=['Title'])

df2['TitleName'] = df2['Title'].str.split('(') #to remove version info 

df2 = pd.concat([df2['Title'], df2.TitleName.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df2.columns=['Title','Software','Version']
df2['Software']=df2.Software.str.replace(' ','(.*)') #create search string in regex format


searchitems= df2["Software"].tolist()

result=[]
for item in searchitems:
    print "searching for : "+item
    print df[df['Software Title'].str.contains(item)]
```

output

```
searching for : Mcrosoft(.*)Word(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Microsoft(.*)Excel(.*)
                                       Software Title
12  Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2010  [ve...
searching for : Microsoft(.*)Access(.*)
                                       Software Title
11  Microsoft Office Access MUI (English) 2010  [v...
searching for : Microsoft(.*)Project(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Microsoft(.*)PowerPoint(.*)
                                       Software Title
13  Microsoft Office PowerPoint MUI (English) 2010...
searching for : Microsoft(.*)Infopath(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Microsoft(.*)Visio(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Microsoft(.*)SQL(.*)Server(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Microsoft(.*)SQL(.*)Client(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Microsoft(.*)explorer(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Firefox(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
searching for : Oracle(.*)Database(.*)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Software Title]
Index: []
```